# How to parse data from column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file contain the following:

[image: original]

and need to parse it and the expected results:

[image: result]

Data in text:

```
id,product_id
    
1,[{'p_id': 59, 'p_name': 'IPF'}, {'p_id': 63, 'p_name': 'RBC'}, {'p_id': 47, 'p_name': 'CSP'}]

2,[{'p_id': 25, 'p_name': 'LPP'}, {'p_id': 86, 'p_name': 'CRS'}, {'p_id': 47, 'p_name': 'CSP'}]

3,[{'p_id': 73, 'p_name': 'OCC'}, {'p_id': 63, 'p_name': 'RBC'}]

4,[{'p_id': 63, 'p_name': 'RBC'}, {'p_id': 31, 'p_name': 'SUT'}, {'p_id': 73, 'p_name': 'OCC'}]

5,[{'p_id': 63, 'p_name': 'RBC'}]
```

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as text as we can not copy the contents from image; Copy first couple of rows from CSV file, and add it to the question

Comment: Please copy as it is in CSV, currently, you have everything in a single line

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just copied it from my text editor.

Comment: The data you have doesn't have string values enclosed inside quote, for e.g. : in `[{'p_id': 59, 'p_name': IPF}`, the value `IPF` is not enclosed by quote, so you can not use any direct method

Comment: My bad, it should have the quote. Edited the data with the quote. Could you help me? Thank you @ThePyGuy

Comment: The answer I have posted will work no matter if quote exists or not

Answer (score 1):

As I have already mentioned in the comment, the data you have doesn't have string values enclosed inside quote, for e.g. : in `[{'p_id': 59, 'p_name': IPF}`, the value `IPF` is not enclosed by quote, so you can not use any direct method.

Out of several way, the easiest way is to use [`yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) (`pip install pyyaml`) package to parse those string values as Python object, then `explode` and apply `pd.Series`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import yaml

filePath = 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filePath, index_col=0)
out = (df['product_id'].apply(lambda x: yaml.load(x, yaml.Loader))
        .explode()
        .apply(pd.Series)
       )
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
>>> out
    p_id p_name
id             
1     59    IPF
1     63    RBC
1     47    CSP
2     25    LPP
2     86    CRS
2     47    CSP
3     73    OCC
3     63    RBC
4     63    RBC
4     31    SUT
4     73    OCC
5     63    RBC
```